# MongoDB Java - Update every sub-array element using another field value

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have an existing collection, containing several documents:

```json
[{
    "_id": "1",
    "someArray": [
        {
            "_id": "1.1"
            "color": "RED"
        },
        {
            "_id": "1.2"
            "color": "GREEN"
        },
        {
            "_id": "1.3"
            "color": "GREEN"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "_id": "2",
    "someArray": [
        {
            "_id": "2.1"
            "color": "WHITE"
        },
        {
            "_id": "2.2"
            "color": "BLUE"
        }
    ]
}, // many others here...
]
```

I need to replace the `color` field of the sub-elements by a `colors` field, which is an array containing the same value `color` did.

Here is the result I want to obtain:

```json
[{
    "_id": "1",
    "someArray": [
        {
            "_id": "1.1"
            "colors": [ "RED" ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "1.2"
            "colors": [ "GREEN" ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "1.3"
            "colors": [ "GREEN" ]
        }
    ]
}, {
    "_id": "2",
    "someArray": [
        {
            "_id": "2.1"
            "colors": [ "WHITE" ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "2.2"
            "colors": [ "BLUE" ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

My closest attempt was this:

```java
collection.updateMany(
    Filters.ne("someArray", Collections.emptyList()),
    Updates.combine(
        Updates.set("someArray.$[].colors", "[ $someArray.color ]"),
        Updates.unset("someArray.$[].color")
    )
);
```

But the value of `colors` is inserted as a String, as-is. It's not interpreted as "an array containing the value of `color` field".

This ***has*** to be done in Java. Please don't provide JS-based solution.

Comment: you can not rename it by regular update query, use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I finally came up with...

```java
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("myCollection");
collection.find(
    Filters.ne("someArray", Collections.emptyList()), MyDocumentRoot.class
).forEach(rootElement -> {
    for(int i = 0; i < rootElement.getSomeArray().size(); i++){
        Document document = collection.find(Filters.eq("_id", rootElement.getId())).first();
        String color = document.getList("someArray", Document.class)
            .get(i)
            .getString("color");
        collection.updateOne(
            Filters.and(
                Filters.eq("_id", rootElement.getId()),
                Filters.eq("someArray._id", rootElement.getSomeArray().get(i).getId())
            ),
            Updates.combine(
                Updates.set("someArray.$.colors", Collections.singleton(color)),
                Updates.unset("someArray.$.color")
            )
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment section, I am afraid this can be done with a simple update query, however, if you are using `MongoDB version 4.2` and above, you can use `$merge` to your advantage, to generate your updated document and merge it in the existing collection like this:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(
                new MongoClientURI(
                        "mongodb://localhost:27017/"
                )
        );
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("StackOverflow");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("Sample");

        FindIterable<Document> result = (FindIterable<Document>) collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(new Document("$match",
                        new Document("someArray",
                                new Document("$exists", true)
                                        .append("$ne", Arrays.asList()))),
                new Document("$unwind",
                        new Document("path", "$someArray")),
                new Document("$set",
                        new Document("someArray.colors", Arrays.asList("$someArray.color"))),
                new Document("$unset", "someArray.color"),
                new Document("$group",
                        new Document("_id", "$_id")
                                .append("someArray",
                                        new Document("$push", "$someArray"))),
                new Document("$merge", "collection")));
```

Here is the working, mongo shell equivalent [pipeline](https://mongoplayground.net/p/spu6LINwnSG).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm using MongoDB 3.6 (for now). In the meantime, I found a Java-based solution. I will publish it now.